# Should I use MongoDB aggregations to filter and process my data, or should I pull all documents and process locally?

Tags: mongodb, performance, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I'm currently trying to use an aggregation to group documents by a field and count how many times that field  equals a specific value within the set of matched documents (i.e. if you have documents structured like`{id: 1, cost: 10}` how many times the cost is 100).
This aggregation is running thousands of times across a dataset of 500k+ entries -  `db.example.aggregate([{'$match': {'id': {'$in': [arrayOfIds]}, 'categoryName': category}}, {'$group': {'_id': '$value', 'count': {'$count': {}}}}])`

I originally was just going to pull all the documents from the collection and manually do that processing in my program, but wanted to see what the performance would look like if I used the aggregation instead. I am iterating through a list of categories, so the aggregation is running many times. The aggregation itself does not take a long time, but running it thousands of times takes awhile. Is this the correct use of aggregations or should they be used more for single queries?

Comment: Why not `"$group"` with something like, `"_id": {"categoryName": "$catName", "value": "$value"}` and skip `"categoryName"` in the `"$match"`?  BTW, it's almost always better to show an example document with all the fields relevant to the aggregation you're interested in.

Comment: Good opportunity to [race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/). The aggregation is _probably_ faster, but since we don't know anything about your specific environment there is no way for us to say anything further